# How do I execute an AWK statement in a Perl script which uses a Perl variable

Tags: perl, awk, grep

I'm trying to use an awk statement inside a perl script which takes user input and searches though a number of text files to find lines which match all the words in the input in any order. To that end, I'm able to do the Awk search I want on the CLI thusly:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ / 204/ && / test/ && / leg/' *_Codes.txt
```

This will return lines in the referenced text files which include words starting with '204', 'test' and 'leg', such as 'left legs being tested in room 2045';

When I try to do this in a Perl script, however, setting the user input to  to a variable and modifying it to include the `&&` operators and slashes, I'm not getting anything back. Here's what I have:

```
my ($code_search, $code_set) = @_;

# Clean the input for awk
# trim whitespace from the ends
$code_search =~ s!(^\s+|\s+$)!!g;

# separate words with the && operator and slashes
$code_search =~ s!\s+!/ && / !g;

# make input lower case and tack on front and back slashes 
my $sanitized_query = lc "/ ${code_search}/";

# at this point, a user input of '204 leg test'
# is transformed to '/ 204/ && / leg/ && / test/'
# and is saved to the $sanitized_query variable

# run the query through awk and save it to $results
my $results = `awk 'tolower($0) ~ \$sanitized_query' *_Codes.txt`;
```

But `$results` doesn't give me anything.

Maybe awk isn't the right tool for the job here, but it seems better suited for my needs than grep is, as I want to make sure I can search for all the terms entered and return results where they all appear in a line of text in any order.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using awk within Perl?  Why not just use Perl?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the search I want in just Perl, a search that returns lines in a text file that contain all the words in the query  in any order. Can you give an example of how to do that?

Comment: You're not going to get the results you expect with that condition: the `&&` has a lower predence than `~`, so you're effectively doing `(tolower($0) ~ / 204/) && / test/ && / leg/` -- the tolower() result does *not* carry over to all 3 match attempts.

Comment: @glennjackman How would I correct that then so the `tolower()` matches all the terms?

Comment: I'd write: `awk '{lwr = tolower($0)} /(^| )204/ && lwr ~ /(^| )test/ && lwr ~ /(^| )leg/' file ...`. If you use GNU awk: `gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/\y204/ && /\ytest/ && /\yleg/' file ...`. The slightly more complicated regexes will match if the word is at the beginning of the line, not just following a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build upon what @mob said, I think this is an escaping issue.
He's escaping too much, though. What you need is something like this:

```
my $results = `awk 'tolower(\$0) ~ $sanitized_query' *_Codes.txt`;
```

You want `$0` to be literal, but `$sanitized_query` to be interpolated. (In your code example above, you're escaping the wrong one).

Comment: Thanks for the great answers, everyone. This one was the most direct and applicable to what I was trying to get done today.

Comment: It won't match your search terms if they appear at the beginning of a line (unlike my Perl implementation which will)

Comment: @hochgurgler I realize that, but that's not really an issue with this particular dataset I'm working with. I was trying to utilize word boundaries within the Awk statement, but wasn't having much luck.

Answer (score 6):

Why not do it entirely in perl, rather than using awk? You should be able open the file, read in each line and print it out if the regex matches. Regular expressions are one of perls best strengths, why not take advantage of them directly rather than trying to call awk?

The only advantage I see to using awk is that you would have to manually list all of the *_Codes.txt files, but that shouldn't be too difficult in perl.

The easiest way to do it in perl, assuming you have a line of text, is simply to run the regex 3 times, one for each portion you're trying to match. For exmaple, if you want to match `204`, `test` and `leg` you should be able to do

```
if (($line =~ m/ 204/i) && ($line =~ m/ test/i) && ($line =~ m/ leg/i)){
    print $line;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I have 2 questions about it. 1) The query to match can be any number of words, so I'd have to split it, loop through them and match each one, correct? And 2) More importantly, the text files I'm searching with this can get very large (750k in one instance). Any potential performance concerns with running multiple matches on each line?

Comment: @MichaelBester The way I'd do it then would be to create an array of the potential search terms, and then iterate over the line for each item in the array. Just make sure to break if you find a non match. 

It may be a little slow performing, but I doubt it would be anything unreasonable. Perl has fairly optimized regular expressions, so I would expect it to be a reasonable speed. 

In any case, the worst scenario is you just go back to using Awk if its too slow.

Comment: @TLP my perl is a little rusty, but wouldn't that result in only a single match? I thought the problem constraint was that you needed to have all of the search terms on the same line. I'm not sure of a particularly efficient way to do that in a single Regular Expression though.

Comment: You're correct, @Skolor, it should match all the terms, not just one, as TLP's answer would do. I'll dig in and try your approach with doing matches for each term shortly.

Comment: All relevant points implemented in my answer beginning "Pure Perl solution"

Answer (score 3):

`$0` is a valid symbol in Perl, too (it contains the name of the currently running Perl script) and is also interpolated inside backquotes. You need to escape it, too:

```
my $results = `awk 'tolower(\$0) ~ \$sanitized_query' *_Codes.txt`;
```

Comment: While this is a good catch, it's not doing the trick. I'm still not getting any results with this one.

Comment: As per @adam-luikart's suggestion below, this does work if you _don't_ escape the $sanitized_query, as I had mistakenly done.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Perl solution, including splitting `$code_search`, globbing the filenames, and matching the patterns only at the beginnings of words:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{ all };

my @words = ($code_search =~ m/\S+/g);

for my $fn (glob('*_Codes.txt')) {
    open my $f, '<', $fn || die "Can't open: $!";

    while (defined(my $line = <$f>)) {
        if (all { $line =~ m{\b\Q$_\E}is } @words) { print $line }
    }

    close $f;
}
```

If you don't want to depend on List::MoreUtils, then change the 'if' to:

```
        if (!grep { $line !~ m{\b\Q$_\E}is } @words) { print $line }
```

— a bit harder to read, but only uses perl builtins.

Comment: This is close. The version using the List::MoreUtils module works (the !grep mod returns everything in the text files), however, what if I wanted to limit it to matches which only begin with the search terms. For example, searching '204 test' would match '20400 test', but not '6204 test' or '204 retest'. Your current implementation would match all 3.

Comment: If you want it to match only on terms which begin with the search terms then you can change the match to start with the word boundary pattern \b so m{\b\Q$_\E}is

Comment: The List::MoreUtils::all version might be better because List::MoreUtils::all quits early as soon as it hits a non-match whereas the grep might run through for all @words regardless

Comment: The !grep version should work just fine. It uses the "!grep !..." idiom to mean "if all", though in this case the inner "!" was implemented by replacing the ordinary match operator ( =~ ) with the negated match operator ( !~ ). If you tried it without changing the inner match operator, then it would return all lines where none of the patterns appeared, which might superficially have looked like "everything".

Comment: Ah, you're right. I hadn't implemented the negated match operator.

Comment: I do like this approach, and may well refactor the module to utilize it. Thanks for your input, @hochgurgler!

Answer (score 1):

While Skolor's answer is completely appropriate, here's a slightly different approach, making use of the [smart match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) (which is available in Perl version 5.10 or greater).  If the lines of your text file are really long and if you don't have a lot of words to check against the lines, this might be a quicker approach (emphasis on "might").

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @query_words=qw(204 test leg);

open(my $read,"<","input_file") or die $!;

while(<$read>)
{
  chomp; #get rid of trailing newline
  my @words=split(/\s+/,$_); #split on spaces to get actual words

  foreach my $q (@query_words)
  {
    if($q~~@words) #If we have a match, print and exit the loop.
    {
      print "$_\n";
      last;
    }
  }
}

close($read);
```